# Is there any mail application that can synchronize accounts settings between several devices?

Tags: windows, android, linux, email-client

I'm currently using Mozilla Thunderbird on differents devices/os for managing many mail accounts (personal/work/gmail/etc).

- Desktop

  - Windows 10
  - Ubuntu 17.4
- Laptop

  - Windows 10
  - Ubuntu 17.4
- Smartphone

  - Android 7

I'm tired of having to manually repeat a settings modification on all devices. It's the reason why I'm looking for a mail application (or third-party service) abble to synchronize accounts settings (excluding backup/restore manipulation).

For example : if I change the signature of a specific mail account, changes are saved online and retrieved later on other devices.

**EDIT**

I just found a brief solution for Thunderbird. All the settings are linked to a specific Mozilla Thunderbird's profile saved on your disk. You can share this profile between all your devices thanks to a networkd shared disk. You can also put the profile on Google Drive, mount your Google Dirve locally thanks to CloudMounter and load this profile. The problem is, Mozilla Thunderbird doesn't exist for Android.

Is there any other software with which I can do the same trick, which exists on Windows/Linux/Android ?